# New Ubuntu/Linux Flavor

Tags: custom-distributions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to customize live Ubuntu CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-live-ubuntu-cd)

i love ubuntu 11.10 but i hate Unity ... we have a team of developers here (15) and we all use ubuntu and we want to have our own "ubuntu" with our software pre-installed.

every time we install ubuntu for a new employee we have to remove

- unity
- evolution
- totem
- (and more)

and we have to install:

- vim
- firefox 7
- yed
- (and more)

is it easy to build a new version or flavor of linux based on ubuntu that match our needs?

thanks

Comment: See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-live-ubuntu-cd/49679#49679).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest something else. You can create your custom ISO with some tools. Remastersys is one of them: http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/

There is a simple howto:
http://www.ubuntugeek.com/creating-custom-ubuntu-live-cd-with-remastersys.html

Also, Relinux is another project:
http://lkubuntu.wordpress.com/2011/10/10/relinux-a-way-to-create-a-bootable-iso-out-of-your-system/

With these tools, you can create your own custom Ubuntu ISO and easily install anywhere.